# Is it an acceptable pattern to put derived classes inside an abstract base class in Java?

Tags: java, design-patterns, inheritance, patterns-and-practices, project-structure

Suppose I have some Java code such as the following (in this case, the use of the name "interaction" is referring to interacting with an object in a video game):

```java
public abstract class Interaction
{
    private Interaction()
    {
        // ...
    }

    // base class stuff here, some public some private

    public static final class OneShotInteraction extends Interaction
    {
        public OneShotInteraction()
        {
            // empty
        }
    }

    public static final class OngoingInteraction extends Interaction
    {
        public OngoingInteraction()
        {
            // ...
        }

        // ...
    }

    public static final class ItemExchangeInteraction extends Interaction
    {
        public ItemExchangeInteraction()
        {
            // ...
        }

        // ...
    }

    public static final class InventoryInteraction extends Interaction
    {
        public InventoryInteraction()
        {
            // ...
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

In this code, I'm defining derived classes for handling different types of interactions that all inherit from a shared base class.

My reasons for structuring the code in this way are:

1. I want to limit the possible types of interactions to the ones defined here. I don't want code from other packages or modules being able to deliberately or inadvertently make their own interaction subclasses.
2. The interaction classes need to be able to access other package-protected members of the package that they're currently in.
3. I don't want to pollute the namespace of the package.

So I can't:

- Put the derived classes in a separate package, because this requires using a public constructor in the base class and breaks (1).
- Put the derived classes plus base class in a separate package, because this breaks (2).
- Put the derived classes outside of the base class in the same package, because this breaks (3).

So my question is, would it be considered a bad pattern to put derived classes inside of their base class in this manner, considering the benefits that I see to namespace organisation and eliminating possible mistakes in the future?

Comment: Please show code that uses such a classs, in order to see how your design restrictions are actually enforced.

Comment: Mostly it comes down to file organization. If the classes are very small, this is convenient. If they are very big, this is inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good deal of opinion in this. I like the pattern and think it has exactly the benefits you mention.

However, here are some things to consider:

- The "don't want to clutter the package" argument is very subjective. You could make the default constructor package-private and just put the subclasses into the same package, in separate files. It's really not that big a deal, and it may be a necessary compromise if other developers balk at the idea of putting all these classes into the same file.
- If you do make them nested classes of `Interaction`, don't repeat that name in the inner classes' names. You will always have to refer to them with a qualified name anyway, and `Interaction.OneShotInteraction` is horrible; `Interaction.OneShot` is good.
- If you are on Java 17 or later, use the new [sealed classes](https://www.baeldung.com/java-sealed-classes-interfaces) feature that's made for exactly this use case.